# How do I prevent a form from being resized by the user?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form that needs to be maximized in VB.net. I don't want the user to be able to change its size or move it around. **How can I do this?**

Comment: @Powerlord How do you know that it isn't some sort of movie player or game where you *want* every last pixel?

Comment: Microsoft provides a comprehensive example as part of its documentation for [Form.FormBorderStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Set the highlighted properties.  Set MaximimSize and MinimizeSize properties the same size

[image]

Comment: Truly a picture is worth a thousand words!

Comment: Show 2016 and 2017 window please. all old are dead.

Comment: @YumYumYum the only way i found for doing this was to define it in the code as i was launching the form

Comment: Controlbox false is not necessary
Changing FormBorderStyle to FixedDialog automatically sets Minimize and Maximize box to false.
Min/Max Size is irrelevant in this case aswell.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent users from resizing, set the FormBoderStyle to Fixed3D or FixedDialog from properties window or from code

```
frmYour.BorderStyle = System.WinForms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D
```

And set the WindowState property to Maximized, set the MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox properties to false.

To prevent the user from moving around, override WndProc

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = 161
        Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
        Const HTCAPTION As Integer = 2
        Const SC_MOVE As Integer = 61456

        If (m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) And (m.WParam.ToInt32() = SC_MOVE) Then
            Return
        End If

        If (m.Msg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) And (m.WParam.ToInt32() = HTCAPTION) Then
            Return
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

Comment: constants for passing to windows api - each integer represents a Windows Message command and corresponding parameter

Comment: This works best, it prevents the user from dragging the form to another monitor too (an issue I have, not sure if it is win 8 or multiple monitors causing this). Mucky (not answerers fault), but the answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Set fixed border
yourForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D

//Set the state of your form to maximized       
yourForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

//Disable the minimize box and the maximize box
yourForm.MinimizeBox = False
yourForm.MaximizeBox = False
```

Answer (score 3):

Set FormBorderStyle to 'FixedDialog'

[image: FixedDialog]

Answer (score 2):

Set the window start style as maximized.  Then, hide the minimize and maximize buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the UI to control this with:

```
frmYour.MinimizeBox = False
frmYour.MaximizeBox = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some code to the Form Load event:

```
me.maximumsize = new size(Width, Height)
me.minimumsize = me.maximumsize
me.maximizebox = false
me.minimizebox = false
```

**Example:** For a Form height and width of 50 pixels each:

```
me.maximumsize = new size(50, 50)
me.minimumsize = me.maximumsize
me.maximizebox = false
me.minimizebox = false
```

Note that setting `maximumsize` and `minimumsize` to the same size as shown here prevents resizing the Form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent resize by dragging sizegrips and by the maximize button and by maximize by doubleclick on the header text, than insert the following code in the load event of the form:

```
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle ' Prevent size grips
    Me.MaximumSize = Me.Size ' Prevent maximize (also by doubleclick of header text)
```

Of course all choices of a formborderstyle beginning with Fixed will do.

Comment: This did it for me

Answer (score -1):

Set the min and max size of form to same numbers.  Do not show min and max buttons.

Comment: As @LarsTech said above you can still pull and resize the form manually in this scenario so this is not the full answer, maybe part of it but wouldnt prevent the issue as a whole

Answer (score -2):

Just change these settings in the Solution Explorer.

```
MaximizeBox = False
MinimizeBox = False
```

The other things such as ControlBox, Locked, and FormBorderStyle are extra.

Comment: `The other things such as ControlBox, Locked, and FormBorderStyle are extra.`  If the FormBorderStyle is not set to a Fixed or None type style, the user can resize the form.

Answer (score -5):

There is an option in vb.net that lets you do all this.

[image: Set <code>lock = false</code> to <code>locked = true</code>]

The user wont be able to re-size the form or move it around, although there are other ways, this I think is the best.

Comment: The locked property is "design time"-only!