# Dissallowing resize of a window form

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want that the user shouldn't be able to resize the window form. I was able to disable the maximize button but wasn't able to find any property to disable resizing.

Any help?

Comment: Bad coder, bad! No gnawing on usability!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent users from changing the window/form size when application is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330339/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-changing-the-window-form-size-when-application-is-r)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set the [FormBorderStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) to [one of the fixed values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

Change the FormBorderStyle to FixedSingle. Also set MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox to False. Even double clicking the title will not maximize the form.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about a WinForms form, you can disable resizing by changing the `FormBorderStyle` property to one of the Fixed values, such as `FixedSingle`. There are also `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize` properties that may be set if you want to allow some, but not total, resizing.

If you are talking about a WPF application, then you can set the `ResizeMode` property to `NoResize`, or you can set the `MaxHeight`, `MaxWidth`, `MinHeight`, and `MinWidth` properties.

As noted in the comments for the question, make sure you have a good reason to disable resizing. Most of the time, there are better alternatives that allow resizing (especially in WPF).

Answer (score 1):

Set MaximumSize and MinimumSize to the current form size

```
  this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);
  this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the frame/border type to a non-resizeable type.