# C#: making a form non-resizable

Tags: c#, forms

In order to make a form non-resizable I have set MaximumSize and MinimumSize to the same value.

The problem I have is that when the user points to the border of the form, the mouse pointer changes so that it look as though the form is resizable.  Is is possible for this not to happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent users from resizing the window/form size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330339/prevent-users-from-resizing-the-window-form-size)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Set `Form.FormBorderStyle` to something else than `Sizable`.

Comment: Set Form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle should be the correct answer. There's one possible FormBorderStyle named SizableToolWindow which will result to a form still sizable but with no maximum/minimum button.

Answer (score 31):

Use this:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Comment: This should be the actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Set `Form.FormBorderStyle to something else than Sizable`" is not enough, need to set `MaximizeBox = False`, or user can change form size by maximum it

Comment: By setting `MaximizeBox` at `False` you deactivate the maximize button on the top right corner
I suggest to do this AND to set `Form.FromBorderStyle` to `FixedDialog`

Answer (score 2):

> [...] `FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog` border style changes the border of the
>   form to that of a dialog box and prevents the form from being resized. [...]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you desire to set this in designer under *Appearance* there is a field to set *FormBorderStyle* this can be changed to something that starts out with *Fixed**.

Answer (score 1):

to make a form not resizable just change the property: FormBorderStyle to anything but not Resizable.

Answer (score 1):

Just go under misc and change sizeable to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
formName.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```