# Disable resizing of a Windows Forms form

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I turn off the user's ability to resize a Windows Forms form?

I'm having it resize itself on a click.

Comment: Set the FormBorderStyle to FixedSingle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a form from being resized by the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119256/how-do-i-prevent-a-form-from-being-resized-by-the-user)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent users from resizing the window/form size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330339/prevent-users-from-resizing-the-window-form-size)

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Take a look at the [FormBorderStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx)

```
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

You may also want to remove the minimize and maximize buttons:

```
form1.MaximizeBox = false;
form1.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Comment: Note that setting `MaximizeBox` to `false` is necessary to prevent the user from maximizing via `Windows key + up`. Setting `ControlBox` to `false` is not good enough.

Answer (score 89):

1. First, select the form.
2. Then, go to the properties menu.
3. And change the property "FormBorderStyle" from sizable to Fixed3D or FixedSingle.

   [image: This is where to modify the property "FormBorderStyle".]

Comment: Perfect ... I put FormBorderStyle property to "FixedSingle" or "Fixed3D" and it is perfect. Users cannot resize the form anymore..

Comment: This one actually stops users from resizing the screen. The accepted answer stops users from having a full screen button and a minimize button.

Answer (score 20):

More precisely, add the code below to the `private void InitializeComponent()` method of the *Form* class:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Answer (score 4):

## Explanation

By default, `FormBorderStyle` property has the **sizable** value `FormBorderStyle.Sizable` assigned. Which enables form to be resized.

There are 7 kinds of `FormBorderStyle` property values available to use.

- None
- FixedSingle
- Fixed3D
- FixedDialog
- Sizable
- FixedToolWindow
- SizableToolWindow

Depending upon the kind of form, we can assign the appropriate value accordingly.
Assuming your form name is `form1`.

Choose any one from below to make it as **Fixed**

**FixedSingle, Fixed3D, FixedDialog** makes the form **non-resizeable**, assigning **None** will also work but won't make sense without a control box in case.

### Code

Code snippets below, use any one of them

> **FixedSingle**

```
    form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

> **Fixed3D**

```
    form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
```

> **FixedDialog**

```
    form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

> **None** [Optional] Note: There'd no control box

```
    form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

---

### Or, Graphically

We can apply it graphically like this.

Make sure you've selected the form which you want to make it fixed size. then you'll see a property named `FormBorderStyle` property there in **Properties** window.

[image: Graphical Properties window of Visual Studio IDE]

Answer (score 0):

There is far more efficient answer: just put the following instructions in the `Form_Load`:

```cs
this.MinimumSize = new Size(Width, Height);
this.MaximumSize = this.MinimumSize;
```

Comment: OP asks for c# and you've given a solution to Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to change properties "AutoSize" (set to True) and "AutosizeMode" (set to GrowAndShrink).

This has the effect of the form autosizing to the elements on it and never allowing the user to change its size.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me, perhaps because my window had a status bar. To fix I did this:

```
StatusStripObject.SizingGrip = False
```

The same works for a StatusBar object, e.g.:

```
StatusBarObject.SizingGrip = False
```