# How do I get the FixedSingle FormBorderStyle to be respected by Windows 7?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, resize, formborderstyle

To prevent the user from resizing a form, I set its FormBorderStyle to FixedSingle, as recommended here:

[Disable Resizing of a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970262/disable-resizing-of-a-windows-form)

This works on XP, but on Windows 7 it doesn't. What has to be done to get it to work on Windows 7 also?

Comment: I'm not seeing this on the win7 32-bit system I run.  Code sample?  Or maybe specific behavior?  Maybe you've got a code update that isn't copying from system to system?

Comment: Specific behavior is: when I run it on my XP machine, I can't resize the form; when another uses runs it on his Windows 7 machine, he can.

Comment: I'd recommend watching him do it if at all possible, then checking executable versions on his machine (possibly in other paths).  politely of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set MinimumSize equal to MaximumSize on the form.