# Can't Change Form Attributes in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I used to program in C#, switched to Java, and now I'm at the point where I have to use both. Well returning to C# has been a bit rough, and I'm having trouble changing an attribute of my form from my code. The goal here is to make it so the window cannot be resized, which, according to [Disable Resizing of a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970262/disable-resizing-of-a-windows-form), consists of me using the code: `form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;`.

However, when I try that, I get "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.FormBorderStyle'". Here's my code thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Audio_File_Management {
    public partial class form1 : Form {
        public form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static void Main() {
            form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the properties of the form?

Comment: Put `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;` under the `InitializeComponent();` line.  Get rid of the Main block.  You could also just do this from the design editor property window.

Comment: What is doing `public static void Main()` here? Instead of `FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle`, you could set the `MaximumSize` and the `MinimumSize` to the same design value, preserving the standard border (if preferable). Anyway, set these properties in the constructor: `public form1() {  (here)  }`

Comment: your class name and object name could not be same

Comment: if your class name is Form1 then you should create object of Form1 class and then use in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct:

```
namespace Audio_File_Management {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
public static Form1 objForm1;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Form1 GetForm()
    {
        if( (objForm1 == null) || objForm1.IsDisposed)
        {
           objForm1 = new Form1();
        }
        return objForm1;
    }

 }
}

public class Program
{
   public static void Main() {
        Form1.GetForm().FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `public static void Main()` doing inside the  Form class? Remove it. Why do you want to return a new instance of the same class and set a property of the new instance. Remove it as well. What remains, `public Form1() {  InitializeComponent();  }` is all that is needed. Set the property there. That's all.

Comment: @Jimi thank you but GetForm() method is create a new instance only when there is not instance available for that Form class.

Comment: @LarsTech . I have updated my code . Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Re-read my comment. You just need to set that property in the Form's constructor. BTW, this is not VB.Net, there are no default Form instances: `public static Form1`? Where have you ever seen this? `public class Program`, here? What does this even mean?

Comment: of course no default Form instances but yes it is possible that form has been disposed and someone wants to re use the same class and when someone want to use the same instance again and again then why he/she do not use method written by me? Program class exist in a seperate file; this is just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: GetForm() method can also be used to pass some parameters before creating a instance of the class

Comment: It's just the wrong way to solve this problem for the end user.  Just have them set the property in the form's designer.  Don't make it complicated.