# How to disable both Resize and Move for a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

my Windows Form `FormBorderStyle` is none, but I want to disable resize function like below code, How Can I implement, Thanks!

```
    //disable move
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

        switch (message.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    return;
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
```

Comment: You want to disable `resize` or `moving` the window?

Comment: I want to disable resize and move both.

Comment: Is your window going to be `maximized` prior to disabling resize and move?

Comment: I have disabled the maximized function.

Comment: Maybe it’s not elegant, but you can look i.e. at the resize event and in case someone tries to resize the form you just set it back to the size you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for

```
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

This will prevent the form to resize.

However if you want to disable the move also then you need to first maximize your form and then disable the resize by setting it `FixedSingle`

Comment: Thanks! But my FormBorderStyle is `none`, could I use `FixedSingle` and `none` at the same time?

Comment: @Andy:- I dont think you can use both at the same.time. However if you want to prevent your form to be resized then you should use FixedSingle only not the none.

Comment: @Andy:- Also if you want to disable the move then first you maximize the form and then disable the resize.

Comment: I want to make the form border invisible, so I set the FormBorderStyle to `none`. Do I have other method to make border invisible and disable move and resize function?

Comment: @Andy:- In that case you can just make it to none and maximize your form next. Also set the property of maximize to true using the property tab of the form.

Comment: @Andy:- Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119256/how-do-i-prevent-a-form-from-being-resized-by-the-user